# Can this code be made short using loop? (see detail)

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I have to write this whole code for a 10 questions quiz. I compare and prepare results through this code. Is there any solution so that I can type this **"if, else if and else conditions"** block only once and apply loop on this and get the same results?

```
$count=0;
$count2=0;

if($ans1==$answer1)
{
    $res1= "Correct";
    $count=$count+1;
}
else if($answer1=="")
{
    $res1="Not attempted";
}
else
{
    $res1= "Incorrect";
    $count2=$count2-1;
}

if($ans2==$answer2)
{
    $res2= "Correct";
    $count=$count+1;
}
else if($answer2=="")
{
    $res2="Not attempted";
}
else
{
    $res2= "Incorrect";
    $count2=$count2-1;
}
if($ans3==$answer3)
{
    $res3= "Correct";
    $count=$count+1;
}
else if($answer3=="")
{
    $res3="Not attempted";
}
else
{
    $res3= "Incorrect";
    $count2=$count2-1;
}

if($ans4==$answer4)
{
    $res4= "Correct";
    $count=$count+1;
}
else if($answer4=="")
{
    $res4="Not attempted";
}
else
{
    $res4= "Incorrect";
    $count2=$count2-1;
}
if($ans5==$answer5)
{
    $res5= "Correct";
    $count=$count+1;
}
else if($answer5=="")
{
    $res5="Not attempted";
}
else
{
    $res5= "Incorrect";
    $count2=$count2-1;
}

if($ans6==$answer6)
{
    $res6= "Correct";
    $count=$count+1;
}
else if($answer6=="")
{
    $res6="Not attempted";
}
else
{
    $res6= "Incorrect";
    $count2=$count2-1;
}
if($ans7==$answer7)
{
    $res7= "Correct";
    $count=$count+1;
}
else if($answer7=="")
{
    $res7="Not attempted";
}
else
{
    $res7= "Incorrect";
    $count2=$count2-1;
}

if($ans8==$answer8)
{
    $res8= "Correct";
    $count=$count+1;
}
else if($answer8=="")
{
    $res8="Not attempted";
}
else
{
    $res8= "Incorrect";
    $count2=$count2-1;
}
if($ans9==$answer9)
{
    $res9= "Correct";
    $count=$count+1;
}
else if($answer9=="")
{
    $res9="Not attempted";
}
else
{
    $res9= "Incorrect";
    $count2=$count2-1;
}

if($ans10==$answer10)
{
    $res10= "Correct";
    $count=$count+1;
}
else if($answer10=="")
{
    $res10="Not attempted";
}
else
{
    $res10= "Incorrect";
    $count2=$count2-1;
}

//INCREASE POINTS IN FOLLOWING STATEMENT ONLY USING 2*$COUNT

$finalpoints=$count+$count2;
$_SESSION["pointsession"]= $finalpoints;
```

Comment: As said, it can be done, look into storing your answers / results in arrays and loop through them :) - Although I don't know why you tagged this as c?

Comment: Store answers in array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use arrays to store the data:

```
$count=0;
$count2=0;

$ans = array($answer1,$answer2,$answer3,...);
$answer = array($ans1,$ans2,$ans3,...);

for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){
   if($ans[$i]==$answer[$i])
  {
      $res[$i]= "Correct";
      $count=$count+1;
  }
  else if($answer[$i]=="")
  {
      $res[$i]="Not attempted";
  }
  else
  {
      $res[$i]= "Incorrect";
      $count--;
  }
}

//INCREASE POINTS IN FOLLOWING STATEMENT ONLY USING 2*$COUNT

$finalpoints=$count+$count2;
$_SESSION["pointsession"]= $finalpoints;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this using arrays

```
$count=0;
$count2=0;

var ans = [$ans1, $ans2.... ];
var answer = [$answer1, $answer2.... ];
var res = [];

answer.forEach(function($answer, i) {
    if(ans[i]==$answer)
    {
        res.push("Correct");
        $count=$count+1;
    }
    else if($answer=="")
    {
        res.push("Not attempted");
    }
    else
    {
        res.push("Incorrect");
        $count2=$count2-1;
    }   
});

$res1 = res[0];
$res2 = res[1];
...
```

Note that the ... indicate code that you have to fill in

Answer (score 0):

Again, assuming that both questions and answers are in arrays

```
        $count=0;
        $ans=array(1,2,3,4,23,1,100);
        $answer=array(1,2,'',4,'',54,100);


        function mark($answer,$correct){
            if( $answer==$correct ) $rv=array('response'=>'correct','score'=>1, 'correct'=>$correct, 'answer'=>$answer );
            elseif( $answer=='' ) $rv=array('response'=>'not attempted','score'=>0, 'correct'=>$correct, 'answer'=>$answer );
            else $rv=array('response'=>'incorrect','score'=>-1, 'correct'=>$correct, 'answer'=>$answer );
            return (object)$rv;
        }

        for( $i=0; $i < count( $ans ); $i++ ){
            $result=mark( $answer[$i], $ans[$i] );
            $count += $result->score;
            echo 'Question '.( $i+1 ).': Correct answer:' . $result->correct.' Your answer:'.$result->answer.' - '.$result->response . ' - score:'.$result->score.'<br />';
        }

        echo 'Final score: '.$count.' / '.count($answer);
```